# Android Studio: Resources$NotFoundException:String Resource

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I am trying to simultaneously edit the `textView_pay` while writing into `editText_num`.Unfortunately , whenever i enter the first letter in the `editText_num` the app returns to the previous activity.

I am posting my last_step_book.java and logcat error here.

the last_step_book.java is :

```
public class last_step_book extends AppCompatActivity 
{
    TextView val;
    TextView num;
    Integer mul;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_last_step_book);
        num = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.editText_num);
        val = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView_pay);
        num.addTextChangedListener(inputTextWatcher1);
    }
    TextWatcher inputTextWatcher1 = new TextWatcher() 
    {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) 
        {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) 
        {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable num) 
        {
            Integer number = Integer.parseInt(num.toString());
            mul = number * 10;
            val.setText(mul);
        }
    };
}
```

The logcat error is :

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: no.nordicsemi.android.nrftoolbox, PID: 9759
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0xa
at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:315)
at android.content.res.MiuiResources.getText(MiuiResources.java:123)
at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4142)
at no.nordicsemi.android.nrftoolbox.last_step_book$1.afterTextChanged(last_step_book.java:39)
at android.widget.TextView.sendAfterTextChanged(TextView.java:7705)
at android.widget.TextView$ChangeWatcher.afterTextChanged(TextView.java:9514)
at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.sendAfterTextChanged(SpannableStringBuilder.java:972)
at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:516)
at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:454)
at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:33)
at android.text.method.NumberKeyListener.onKeyDown(NumberKeyListener.java:121)
at android.widget.TextView.doKeyDown(TextView.java:5813)
at android.widget.TextView.onKeyDown(TextView.java:5626)
at android.view.KeyEvent.dispatch(KeyEvent.java:2635)
at android.view.View.dispatchKeyEvent(View.java:8418)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1496)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1496)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1496)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1496)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1496)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1496)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1496)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2364)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1709)
at android.app.Activity.dispatchKeyEvent(Activity.java:2719)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.dispatchKeyEvent(AppCompatActivity.java:534)
at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchKeyEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:58)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase$AppCompatWindowCallbackBase.dispatchKeyEvent(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:316)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2279)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processKeyEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4068)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:4030)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3587)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3640)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3606)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3723)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3614)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3780)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3587)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3640)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3606)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3614)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3587)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5855)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:5829)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5800)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewRootHandler.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:3383)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5276)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:911)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(Zyg
```

Where is the error?? And how can it be rectfied??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this

```
val.setText(String.valueOf(mul));
```

instead of this

```
 val.setText(mul);
```

and also change this `editText_num`

Use this

```
EditText num = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_num);
```

instead of this

```
num = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.editText_num);
```

Comment: Thanks it worked!!@Prem

Comment: @VINNYKINGER happy to help you my friend

Answer (score 0):

try to set text by

```
val.setText(String.valueOf(mul));
```